# Disable CLI program on session start

Tags: boot, ssh

I'm helping a friend who has a raspberry which has been configed by a former colleague.

What happens is on every session open, a foreground CLI program starts which prevents me from controlling the raspberry.

`Ctrl+C`, `Ctrl+Z` or `Ctrl+D`-ing it doesn't work :(

I am looking for a way to either login without starting the program, or to exit it. Here are the technical details:

- on boot, the program starts
- on `ssh pi@<IP>`, the program starts
- on `ssh root@<IP>`, the program starts

Any idea? Like a super `Ctrl+C` or a maintenance mode on SSH, or raspberry?

Thanks

---

EDIT: I removed the SD card and here's what's inside `/etc/passwd`:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/sh
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/sh
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/bin/sh
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/bin/sh
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/bin/sh
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/bin/sh
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/bin/sh
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/bin/sh
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/bin/sh
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/sh
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/bin/sh
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/bin/sh
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/bin/sh
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/bin/sh
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/bin/sh
libuuid:x:100:101::/var/lib/libuuid:/bin/sh
pi:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/pi:/bin/bash
sshd:x:101:65534::/var/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
messagebus:x:102:104::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
avahi:x:103:105:Avahi mDNS daemon,,,:/var/run/avahi-daemon:/bin/false
ntp:x:104:107::/home/ntp:/bin/false
statd:x:105:65534::/var/lib/nfs:/bin/false
usbmux:x:106:46:usbmux daemon,,,:/home/usbmux:/bin/false
lightdm:x:107:110:Light Display Manager:/var/lib/lightdm:/bin/false
```

Doesn't seem to execute any program, does it?

Comment: Can you tell us which program starts? If it is a browser in full screen mode you can try `F11` to leave full screen mode.

Comment: I think that program had been set up as the login shell. Take the sd card out of the Pi and check/edit its /etc/passwd on another machine.

Comment: This is getting interesting @Jank! What should I look for inside the `/etc/passwd` file? I edited my question with the content

Comment: The last field of the *pi* and *root* lines. It should read `/bin/bash` or another shell installed on the system. But it seems that's okay. You should check /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile next.

Comment: I found the program and commented the `trap '' SIGINT` guilty line. So now after login I can `Ctrl+C` so I'm good